# In Visual Studio 2013, is it possible to post links in one code file that takes you right to a line in another code file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a situation where every time I edit an attribute in my html file then I have to be careful to edit the javascript file that depends on these attributes also.

I want to post inline code links so I can click back and forth between the two code lines that depend on each other. Can I do it?

The code links should be like using cref in comments, except I can click on them in Visual Studio.

The code links should be permanent, so someone with a different .suo file can see them as well.

The code links should link between files of different languages.

The code links should not only take you to a file but also a particular line of code.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of the Javascript and the HTML?

Comment: Seems web development has a lot of instances of the programmer having to keep strings named the same. If I can't use a refactor tool it would be nice to have inline code links to remind me, or indeed another coder that one area depends on another and make it easy for them to get to the other area.

Comment: Maybe you can use bookmarks for your specific case http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wffxsy0.aspx

Comment: Can I link to the bookmarks in code?

Comment: @IsaacBolinger It says: "You can navigate between bookmarks by using the Next Bookmark and Previous Bookmark buttons in the bookmark window." You bookmark the line you want and that's all so you can switch fast from interested lines.

Comment: Yeah but I want a permanent link, like how comments are permanent

Comment: I know it seems like an extravagant demand, but they would certainly come in handy and improve things ever so slightly.

Comment: @IsaacBolinger Don't know about that, sorry. Maybe time to make your own extension using Roslyn.